# Visual Studio can't 'see' my included header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, include

I created an empty 'Demo' project in Visual Studio 2008 and added some existing projects to my solution. Included "MyHeader.h" (other project's header) in `main.cpp` file which is in 'Demo'. Also added header files' path in "Tools/Option/VC++ Directories/Include files" section. But intellisense says: "File `MyHeader.h` not found in current source file's directory or in build system paths..."

How the problem can be fixed?

Comment: There is difference between #include <file.h> and #include "file.h".  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename
Also I would suggest you to use relative path instead of using VS directories. This will ensure that the project is location independent.

Comment: does only intellisense give these error (i.e. does the normal build run fine)? then I would try to stop visual studio (possibly remove .suo/.sdf files for the affected projects), restart vs

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you choose `Project` and then `All Files` in the menu, all files should be displayed in the Solution Explorer that are physically in your project map, but not (yet) included in your project. If you right click on the file you want to add in the Solution Explorer, you can include it.

Answer (score 32):

Delete the .sdf file that is in your solution directory. It's just the Intellisense database, and Visual Studio will recreate it the next time you open that solution. This db can get corrupted and cause the IDE to not be able to find things, and since the compiler generates this information for itself on the fly, it wouldn't be affected.

Comment: This typically is needed when you manually modify project files (*.vcxproj and *.vcxproj.user): the IDE has no idea about your changes and hence does not update intellisense database accordingly.

Comment: Works for me in visual studio 2015

Comment: With VS2017 I found Browse.VC.db and Solution.VC.db in project_dir/.vs/project_name/v15/ and deleted these files. Intellisense was then able to correclty recreate its db.

Comment: With VS2019: Close VS and delete the hidden .vs directory in the project directory. Then compile again. Works for me.

Comment: With VS2019 and CUDA headers: helped to delete Browse and Solution VC dbs only, like suggested before.

Answer (score 8):

This happened to me just now, after shutting down and restarting the computer. Eventually I realised that the architecture had somehow been changed to ARM from x64.

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio 2019 in my case I copied a header file into the project directory, just near the other files. Intellisense could see it, but the build failed. Fair enough, it wasn't actually added to the project. I added it as existing item but this is the point that Visual Studio still didn't account for it.
Solution:

1. Close the project.
2. Delete the `.vs` directory.
3. Reopen the project.
   Now Visual Studio recreates the directory with everything in it and it can now see the included file.

Answer (score 3):

If it is the case that only the IDE indicates that it cannot find included files, but compiling is successful, the issue is simply that IntelliSense is not fully up to date with recent changes. This can happen specifically when including existing projects, in my own experience.
Deleting the .sdf file (= IntelliSense database) that is generated in your solution directory forces Visual Studio to regenerate it, so that it is up to date again. Just doing a "clean" will probably do the same thing, but takes more time since everything will be generated again then.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older question, but none of the above answers worked for me. In my case, the issue turned out to be that I had absolute include paths but without drive letters. Compilation was fine, but Visual Studio couldn't find an include file when I right-clicked and tried to open it. Adding the drive letters to my include paths corrected the problem.

I would never recommend hard-coding drive letters in any aspect of your project files; either use relative paths, macros, environment variables, or some mix of the tree for any permanent situation. However, in this case, I'm working in some temporary projects where absolute paths were necessary in the short term. Not being able to right-click to open the files was extremely frustrating, and hopefully this will help others.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. Double check if you added the include files to **Debug** or **Release** Version of your project. If you only added it for one of them and compile for the other VS will just play dumb and not find them.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I just realized that I need to do all the configuration steps to the release configuration as well. I thought it already applied to all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the header file to your project's files. (right click on project -> add existing file).

Comment: that doesn't make compiler find your headers - you need to set the include directory for that

Comment: @RandolphCarter he is talking about intellisense not the compiler. I am aware that this does not help the compiler. What the compiler needs is the setting in "Tools/Option/VC++ Directories/Include files" that he has already set.

Comment: Adding the headers helps intellisense? weird, shouldn't compiler and intellisense use the same options?

Comment: Thankfully, 2010 and beyond addressed this, and many other issues with IntelliSense. Still not perfect, but better.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, with VS2010, when include files can't be found at compile time, doing a clean, then build usually fixes the problem. It's not that rare for the editor to be able to open an include file and then the compiler to announce that it can't find that very file, even when it is open on the screen!

Answer (score 1):

If the visual studio says that you miss some file in the current source file folder, there is one solution that i used. Just right click the file you want to add and choose `Open Document`, if it really doesn't exist, then you should see something like `cannot find file in the source file path = "somewhere in your computer"`, then what you could do is the add your source file into that path first and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue after upgrading to Visual Studio 2019 from 2015. It would compile the project fine but Intellisense and the IDE couldn't find any header files.

The project only had valid configuration for Win32/Debug. Include paths were not setup correctly for other environments. Even though Visual Studio displayed the current environment as Win32/Debug, Intellisense must have been using something else.

Changing the current environment to x64/Release, and then back to Win32/Debug fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, click on `Project` > `Rescan Solution` as shown below to rebuild the project database.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this problem.

- ***Go to Project --> Show All Files.***

[image]

- ***Right click all the files in Solutions Explorer and Click on Include in Project in all the files you want to include.***

[image]

Done :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue, but the solutions provided didn't directly help me, so I'm sharing how I got myself into a similar situation and temporarily resolved it.

I created a new project within an existing solution and copy & pasted the Header and CPP file from another project within that solution that I needed to include in my new project through the IDE. Intellisense displayed an error suggesting it could not resolve the reference to the header file and compiling the code failed with the same error too.

After reading the posts here, I checked the project folder with Windows File Explorer and only the **main.cpp** file was found. For some reason, my copy and paste of the header file and CPP file were just a *reference*? (I assume) and did not physically copy the file into the new project file.

I deleted the files from the Project view within Visual Studio and I used File Explorer to copy the files that I needed to the project folder/directory. I then referenced the other solutions posted here to *"include files in project"* by showing all files and this resolved the problem.

It boiled down to the files not being physically in the Project folder/directory even though they were shown correctly within the IDE.

**Please Note** I understand duplicating code is not best practice and my situation is purely a learning/hobby project.  It's probably in my best interest and anyone else who ended up in a similar situation to use the IDE/project/Solution setup correctly when reusing code from other projects - I'm still learning and I'll figure this out one day!

Answer (score 0):

If some soul has scrolled down to this bottom, what worked for me was ***disabling*** the `Disable Database` option i.e. set it to `False` under `Tools|Options|Text Editor|C/C++|Advanced`. For some reason, it was set to `True` for me.

[image]

As per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-c-cpp-advanced?view=vs-2019#browsingnavigation), if it's set to `True`

> All use of the code browsing database (SDF), all other
> Browsing/Navigation options, and all IntelliSense features except for
> #include Auto Complete are disabled.

Answer (score -1):

None of the solutions worked for me. Here is what was the issue for me:
(Note discrepancy in build configuration and VC++ Directories (x86 vs x64)

[image]

To fix, just changed the build configuration to 'x86':

[image: As shown here]