# Visual Studio 2017 can't see include files and folders

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, include

i have simple project which using external directory with include files 
but from some reason it doesn't see the folder what ever i do 
including following this answer :
[Visual Studio can't 'see' my included header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490015/visual-studio-cant-see-my-included-header-files)

here is picture that shows that i include the files/directories 
but the cpp file still shows that it can't find it

[image]

also added manually 
[image]
what else i can check to see why this is happening

**UPDATE**

The answer is that you need to add the path in the additional directories also

Comment: This screenshot only shows that you have a folder named "includes" that contains some header files. Compilers won't automatically look in it for included headers (regardless of whether that folder is a part of the project or not). So you should add path to that folder into "Additional include directories" `/I`.

Comment: ```#include "Magick++.h"```?

Comment: You have to use #include "Magical++.h" if the file exist in the same location as the .cpp file you are including in or give relative path. But it is recommended to add the include paths in Additional Include directory and you can refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories?view=vs-2019 for that.

Comment: i did it also , manually set the additional include path .. full path 
see updated answer

Comment: It could be failing because you are building in "Release" mode and you have added the path in "Debug" configuration. If you have made the same configuration changes in "Release" too, create a sample project, upload and provide the link to take a look at that.

Comment: no the answer is that you need to add the path to the additional includes after you 
added them via add includes click