# Usage Imagemagick library in C++ Visual Studio Code Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, imagemagick, magick++

in my first C++ project in Visual Studio Code I have troubles in including the external library Imagemagick (imagemagick.org) Magick++.h [Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm8OW.png)

I installed the library files and linked the installation folder in c_cpp_properties.json
[Pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4ep2.png)

Therefore, when I include the library I do not have any "wavy line", which marks a non found library [Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMo2m.png)

Anyhow, whenever I try to compile with

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.25.28610/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
```

I get:

IMhelloworld.cpp

```
c:\Users\jfi\Desktop\Hints_Scripts\InsortAP_Toolbox\VSCode\IMHelloWorld\IMhelloworld.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht geöffnet werden: "Magick++.h": No such file or directory
```

Please help! What am I missing?

Thank you so much!

Best regards
LeFish

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4ep2.png)

Comment: If you are using the C++ binding to ImageMagick, you should use the [tag:magick++] tag to attract the correct people.

Comment: This may be the solution...https://stackoverflow.com/a/18068069/2836621

Comment: Thanks! I am on VSCode and therefore do not have these menus.

I also tried with an other compiler (MINGW). Same result. I can add the mingw-standard-libraries (like iostream etc) and the compiler finds it.
But whenever I add the magick++.h it is only found by IntelliSense but not by the compiler.

Comment: Could you describe in detail exactly how you are compiling. I.e. what buttons you press, or menu options you choose or commands you type.

Comment: I think I have found a completely different approach: Conan Package Manager

The only problem is, I don't know how to start. Would you guys kindly give me some boost please?

I am a total beginner with this using MinGW g++ compiler right now.

Answer (score 1):

Post was:

> Your includePath says `"C:\\Program
>   Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.9-Q8\\include"`
>
> But the header files are in
>   `"C:\\Programme\\ImageMagick-7.0.9-Q8\\include"`

Thanks, corrected that.

Comment: You get today's *"Eagle-eyed Viewer Award"*!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

But even after fixing this, there is the same error on compiling.

When I right-click on the #include line and hit "Go to definition" it atually opens the content of Magick++.h

So Virtual Studio Code sees the library files. Just the compiler does not.

Comment: @LeFish I'm not sure what to suggest as I don't know Visual Studio Code. Maybe you need to refresh the project somehow after correcting c_cpp_properties.json? You could always try recreating the project from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I finally have a solution.

I installed CMake and the CMake extension for VSCode.

According to this tutorial [on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yFPO1ofyF0&list=PLK6MXr8gasrGmIiSuVQXpfFuE1uPT615s) I got a functioning development environment.

To add an external library to the project I copied all the necessary files to an "include" folder within my project workspace.
I made Cmake aware of this folder by the following CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(IMHelloWorld VERSION 1.0.0)

add_executable(IMHelloWorld main.cpp)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

After this I was able to compile the project with

```
cmake ..
```

and

```
cmake --build .
```

as described in the linked videos.